# Perl - Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key "Error : unrecognized key format"

Tags: perl, encryption, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to generate a token for an Http request call based on a private key generated using OpenSSL RSA (2048) and then a public key, which is generated by the group that has the API we're calling.  One side of the token string is encrypted using the public key the other with the private key.  The private key encryption works with the code below but calling the `Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key(public key string)` fails with the "Error : unrecognized key format" issue.  I'm not sure what's wrong with the key but given that the other one works (and was supposedly generated using same OpenSSL unix tool) it seems odd.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dave

```
use strict;

use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday );
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::X509;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::Random;
use MIME::Base64;
use DateTime;


my $sysTime=undef;
my $sTime=undef;
my $sAPIToken;

my $EDMPrivateKey=qq~
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<private key base 64>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
~;

my $DMPublicKey=qq~
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsftmdt4aAZ7B1F7wVjIz0RSO6w1bIX/4
<rest of public key>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
~;

sub setTime() {
    my $ms;
    my $ms2;
    my $microSec;
    my $tz;
    ($sysTime,$microSec) = gettimeofday();
#    $sysTime=gettimeofday();
    $ms=sprintf("%.*s",3,$microSec);
    $ms2=$microSec-($ms*1000);
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime($sysTime);

    $sTime=sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d-%04d",
                                   $year+1900,$mon+1,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec,$ms,$tz);
    $sysTime=$sysTime*1000+$ms;
}

sub setTimeNew() {
    my $ms;
    my $ms2;
    my $microSec;
    ($sysTime,$microSec) = gettimeofday();
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime($sysTime);
    $ms=sprintf("%.*s",3,$microSec);
    $ms2=$microSec-($ms*1000);

    my $dt=DateTime->new(
      year       => $year+1900,
      month      => $mon+1,
      day        => $yday,
      hour       => $hour,
      minute     => $min,
      second     => $sec,
      nanosecond => $microSec*1000
    );
    $sysTime=$sysTime*1000+$ms;
    $sTime=$dt->strftime("%C%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%z");
}


sub main() {
    my $sTokenPt1;
    my $sTokenPt2;
    my $sPubStr;

    my $rsaPublic  = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($DMPublicKey);
    $rsaPublic->use_sha1_hash();

    setTimeNew();

    $sTokenPt1 = encode_base64($rsaPrivate->encrypt($sysTime));
    $sTokenPt2 = encode_base64($rsaPublic->encrypt($sTime));

    printf "%d\n%s\n",$sysTime,$sTime;
    $sAPIToken = sprintf("%s,%s",$sTokenPt1,$sTokenPt2);
    printf "%d\n%s\nTTOKEN=%s\n",$sysTime,$sTime,$sAPIToken;


}
eval {
    main();
};

if ($@) {
    printf "Error : %s\n",$@;
}
```

Comment: This issue was resolved, turns out using a qq~~ quote for the private/public keys was the culprit.  If I read the keys from the ".pem" file they are loaded fine.